# CodeIgniter 4 and Symfony console issue: not able to use Query Builder

Tags: php, symfony, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter 4. I added some code to my CI 4 project to be able to use Symfony console. The code is working and I'm able to run a command from terminal and see it working.
Below is my code and files structure.
[image: Symfony files location]
Console.php

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__))) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Console\ProcessOrderCommand;

$app = new Application();
$app->add(new ProcessOrderCommand());
$app->run();
```

ProcessOrderCommand.php

```
<?php

namespace Console;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class ProcessOrderCommand extends Command {

    const PROCESS_COMMAND_NAME = 'order:process';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure(): void {
        $this
                ->setName(self::PROCESS_COMMAND_NAME)
                ->setDescription('Process queued orders.')
                ->setHelp('This command processes queued orders.');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $output->writeln('<comment>Demonstration that synfony console works...</comment>');
        return 0;  
        
    }

}
```

My composer.json file has these key, values properties to make everything working.
I run `composer dumpautoload`

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "app/ThirdParty/Console"
        }
    ],
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\Support\\": "tests/_support",
            "Console\\": "app/ThirdParty/Console"
        }
    }
}
```

If I run my command from terminal it works fine see below:
[image: Symfony command working]

I'm trying to get access to CodeIgniter database query builder from inside the file ProcessOrderCommand. I tried everything (library, module creation...) with no success including the code below:

```
public function __construct() {
        $db = \Config\Database::connect();
        parent::__construct();
}
```

[image: DB query builder not working]

Can anyone explain to me if I'm completely outside CI 4 framework and it is impossible to use the query builder or does anyone know a way of doing it?

Thank you.

Comment: The class is not found, so it's an autoloader issue.

Comment: Autoloader is already loading as per my code. Thanks.